# A sequence with successive terms getting arbitrarily close together that is not Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Specifically, I'm trying to find a sequence $x_n$ with the difference of successive terms less than $1/n^2$ for every positive integers $n$ that is not Cauchy: $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<1/n^2$.

I thought about trying some variation involving log $n$, but I can't quite get it to work out.

Comment: Such a sequence of reals would be convergent, and so Cauchy.

Comment: A sequence whose successive terms are less than 1/n^2 would converge?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of the “integral test” for *series* in $mathbb{R}$. (It is not hard to find a convergent series whose partial sums form the sequence you describe.)

Comment: Since the series summing up terms $1/n^2$ has a difference of successive terms equal to $1/n^2$, wouldn't any sequence with successive terms less than $1/n^2$ converge by comparison test?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{n}$ works perfectly (if this is the distance between successive terms, the distance becomes arbitrarily small but the sequence fails to be Cauchy). If you want your distance to drop off as $\frac{1}{n^2}$, by the integral test your sequence will converge and hence be Cauchy.